# How to store an element in a variable from array in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-6

I want to store the "area" in the `$area` variable from `$school_info array`. Using `$area` I want more 3 rows stored into 3 different arrays like: `$school_info1`, `$school_info2`, `$school_info3`.

```php
public function schooldetailviewid($id)
{
    $school_id = $id;
    $school_info = DB::table('school_infos')->where('school_id', '=', $school_id)->get();
    $area = $school_info->area;

    // recomendation start
    $school_info1 = DB::table('school_infos')->where('area', '=', $area)->get();
    $school_info2 = DB::table('school_infos')->where('area', '=', $area)->get();
    $school_info3 = DB::table('school_infos')->where('area', '=', $area)->get();
    // recomendation end

    return view('schooldetail', compact('school_info', 'school_info1', 'school_info2', 'school_info3'));
}
```

**Problem: Storing of elements is not working and also the 3 more rows are not fetched!** I am trying to make a simple recommendation system.

**Error**

> Exception Property [area] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: what is your `school_infos` table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get()` returns an array of objects to get only one object use `.first()`:

```
$school_info = DB::table('school_infos')->where('school_id', '=', $school_id)->first();
$area = $school_info->area;
```

Otherwise, you need to access the first element of the array:

```
$school_info = DB::table('school_infos')->where('school_id', '=', $school_id)->get();
$area = $school_info[0]->area;
```